# How to safely and correctly convert a number from user input to double?

Tags: c#, double, user-input, cultureinfo

This is, basically, a CultureInfo problem. Formally, in my country, the decimal separator is a comma (,) and a thousands separator is a dot (.). In practice, however, this is only used by accountants and diligent people. Normally people never use a thousands separator, and they use both a comma and a dot interchangeably as a decimal separator. I've seen this being the problem even in some Excel spreadsheets that I received from other people, with Excel not having recognized a dot as a decimal separator, leaving the field formatted as a string, rather than a number.

My "solution" thus far has been to simply replace all commas in user input with dots and then parsing the double with InvariantCulture, like so:

```
string userInput;
...
userInput = userInput.Replace(',', '.');
double result;
double.TryParse(userInput, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out result);
```

This will obviously fail when someone actually enters the thousands separator and this seems to me more like a hack than a real solution. So, other than making my own parser for doubles, are there any cleaner ways to handle this problem?

Comment: You need some consistency in the values parsed otherwise there is no absolute way to parse your value. Perhaps just replacing the *last* ',' with a '.' will help.

Comment: If a thousands separator is '.' then it won't. I realize I should probably set some ground rules for formatting, I'm just conflicted between choosing the formal rules which nobody follows, or the informal ones (no thousands separator and interchangeable '.' or ',' as decimal separator), which almost everyone follows. Moreover, I'm only familiar with the situation in my country. Elsewhere people may or may not follow the rules as described in their CultureInfo.

Comment: I would generally say to follow the standard and expect people to follow in suit. There is a reason the 'ground rules' exist and it sounds like it's time to break people of their bad habits.

Comment: I appreciate that sentiment, but it sounds idealistic seeing as these 'ground rules' have recently been changing in my country. Formerly we had a blank as a thousands separator and a dot as decimal separator, then alternating comma and dot for thousands and dot for decimals, and now dot for thousands and comma for decimals. If I made my programs follow such 'ground' rules, I'd never again work as a programmer in Croatia.

Comment: Then it sounds like you already have a solution to your previous comment. Either way, you will be unable to consistently parse your user input. You will have to draw a line in the sand somewhere and/or implement rules in your code based on the input (e.g if the input contains a ' ' then use x pattern otherwise use y). There is no magic that will solve your problem here.

Comment: So far the solution was what I wrote in my question. I'm not asking for magic, I'm asking if there's already something within the .NET framework which can save me the trouble of writing a parser from scratch. I'm thinking along the lines of having it interpret a string as a number and converting it to invariant culture and reporting success or failure, or automatically trying to determine which CultureInfo it might fit.

Comment: Even then, good luck producing what the user expects. My original comment stands; there is **no** way to *consistently* parse *inconsistent* input.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking either. I clearly defined formal rules and what informal rules are followed. But even if users are inconsistent, then maybe there is a way to programmatically force the user to give consistent input? Like a TextBox which automatically formats user's input according to his CultureInfo and what he's expected to type in.

Comment: If you are using ASP.Net you can use the AjaxControlToolkit FilteredTextBox http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/FilteredTextBox/FilteredTextBox.aspx    You can also accomplish the task using RegEx and pattern matching. It is nearly always better to try and get a standard input than attempting to deal with every possible human input variable.

Comment: @Lloyd Thanks. Care to post that as an answer (particularly the part about RegEx and pattern matching, as I don't use ASP.Net)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using ASP.Net you can use the [AjaxControlToolkit FilteredTextBox](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/FilteredTextBox/FilteredTextBox.aspx) you can also accomplish the task using [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx) and pattern matching. It is nearly always better to try and get a standard input than attempting to deal with every possible human input variable.

Some other links:
[MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx)
[WPF Tools FilteredTextBox](http://wpfdevelopertools.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

If there are rules that can conclusively determine what they meant, then you can code the logic. With this problem, though, it is impossible to know the intent in every case:

```
1,001 === 1.001 or 1001
```

Also, even though any "better" logic might assume that numbers like "1,01" are unambiguous, such an entry might be a typo of "1,001." How likely this is depends on what kind of data you're gathering.

If people rarely use a thousands separator, then your existing logic seems good. If you want to be 100% certain of intent, though, the only way to be sure is to ask them what they meant in such cases. E.g. if someone enters `1,001` or `1.001` then fail validation, but recode it as "1,001.0" (or .00 if dealing with currency) to disambiguate it, forcing them to resumbit it.

In practice, you probably would cause more harm than good with this kind of abundance of caution since people don't really use the thousands separator. I'd stick with what you got.